# add extra filter (user input) in search results webpart

Tags: 2013, search

Dears,

in the current project, the client request advance search which enables the user to type search keyword and specify a date range and choose the entity type to search in (entity type like news , events , image gallery, document library, etc .........nearly, all the modules of the project)

so, I'm trying to implement this by the SharePoint out of the box features

I know that advanced search web part had been removed starting from SharePoint 2013

kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, all the information that you need can be achieved by setting up a `Search results web part` along with a `Search Refinement Panel`. The user can type the query using a `Search Query web part`. All these web parts will need to be connected. This will pretty much look like the OOTB search page in Sharepoint, only customized for your needs.

The content which you want crawled needs to be setup using a custom result source.

The refinement panel will allow you to add what you described above for the searched content (specify a date range and choose the entity type to search in (entity type like news , events , image gallery, document library, etc .........nearly, all the modules of the project) and any custom metadata can also be surfaced as long as it is a `Managed property` that is set to `Searchable` and `Refinable`.

Comment: many thanks for your interest and time, but kindly could you provide me with a link to article or a vedio

Comment: Here you go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol8ZpzV1qVI